# gcc Multiple definition...release only

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files, inlining

I have defined a function within a header file. In debug, it compiles and links fine. In release, I get the compile error "multiple definition of `blah::blah(blah& blah)'" for every object file of every class that includes the header.

I'm using gcc-4.8.1. I can't post up the actual code, this version has names changed to protect the innocent:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_SMELLS_FUNNY
#define INCLUDE_SMELLS_FUNNY

#include "ParentClass.h"
#include "ChildClassA.h"
#include "ChildClassB.h"

namespace someplace {

bool smellsFunny(const ParentClass& someData) {

  // All ChildClass As smell funny
  if(dynamic_cast<const ChildClassA*>(&someData)) {
    return true;
  }

  // If ChildClass B, need to check if smells funny
  const ChildClassB* childB = dynamic_cast<const ChildClassB*>(&someData)
   if(childB) {
    return childB->MoreThanAWeekOld();
  }

  // Default is smells OK
  return false;
}

}

#endif // INCLUDE_SMELLS_FUNNY
```

I haven't been able to find which gcc flag is responsible. 
Of course, a fix is just to move the implementation into a cpp file. But why is this necessary? Why does this happen only in release?

Comment: To better answer why it differs between "debug" and "release" builds, you need to show *how* you build for "debug" and "release".

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite new to this whole makefile thing, having come from a VS background. The settings don't appear to be centralized. We have a whole tree of makefiles, make lists and config files.
Is the compiler output for each of the object files that fails sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say exactly but maybe in the debug mode the function is considered as inline function.

Comment: Please explain. I am having this problem on Netbeans on Linux, gcc 4.9.2. My header files have include guards and I am not #including cpp files, yet the project compiles as debug but fails to compile as release. Also my headers do not contain any definitions just declarations. Oddly I can compile the sources on the command line.

Comment: @Olumide  It is difficult to say anything without seeing your current code. Create a new thread here with a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have placed the function definition in the header, you need to mark it `inline`:

```
inline bool smellsFunny(const ParentClass& someData) { ...
```

This is because every place in which you include the header will have a definition of the function, breaking the *one definition rule (ODR)*. `inline` lets you work around the ODR.

As to why there is no problem in release mode, that doesn't make sense: the code is not correct. It could be that release mode is declaring the function inline for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you *define* the function in a header file, and then include that header file in multiple source files. That means the function will be defined in each source file (technically, translation unit) where you include the header.

There are a couple of solutions to this:

1. Mark the function as `static`. That means that each definition in the translation units will not be exported.
2. Mark the function as `inline`. This works basically the same as the first alternative.
3. Put the *definition* of the function in a source file, and only have its *declaration* in the header file.

For a small function like the one you have, then alternative 2 might be a good one. If you have a larger function, that can't easily be inlined, you should go with alternative 3.

Also, if you go with number 3, then you don't need to include the header files, and then lessen the risk of circular inclusion.

Comment: Yep, adding inline fixed it. The word d'oh comes to mind. 
I had a bit of a blind spot on this because I thought if anything inlining would be an optimization. But I see I had it the wrong way round: e.g. auto-inlining is turned off if you set -O2

Comment: @Mijin Marking a function `inline` is only a *hint* to the compiler, that it may inline it if it wants to. Otherwise it works the same as making the function `static`.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is in a header file, you need to declare it `inline`, unless it's defined within a class.